# Wiremock Priority with Scenario

Tags: rest, networking, wiremock

I have two wiremock stubbings, the first one is more detailed and the second one is more general. I have a url request is `The GET request to url http://sky-stub:8080/abc/sky/api/orgs/b44bddb5-5f15-4aee-a8cd-496721124f61/groups/1b694fb8-69af-4c36-a861-631bb93cc67c` which always hits the second stubbing. I even using the priority 2 and 20 to want this request to hit the first stubbing, but it doesn't work.

The first stubbing:

```
{
  "priority": 2,
  "scenarioName": "Sync routes for non existing group",
  "requiredScenarioState": "TheFirstGet",
  "newScenarioState": "AfterFirstGetGroup",
  "request": {
    "urlPattern": "/abc/sky/api/orgs/(.*)/groups/1b694fb8-69af-4c36-a861-631bb93cc67c",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status" : 200,
    "bodyFileName" : "sync-routes/get-group-response.json",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

The second stubbing:

```
{
  "priority": 20,
  "request": {
    "urlPattern": "/abc/sky/api/orgs/(.*)/groups/(.*)",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status" : 200,
    "bodyFileName" : "group.json",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another stub that is setting the ScenarioState to "TheFirstGet"? By default, all Scenarios begin in a ScenarioState of "Started". I would think that changing the `requiredScenarioState` to `Started` would fix your problem.

Comment: I have another stub of which "requiredScenarioState" is "AfterFirstGetGroup", and I tried it with your suggestion, and it works for the first call the url, it goes to the first sub listed above. However, the second call of this url doesn't goes to my another sub, it still goes to the second stub that list above.

Comment: Is the second mapping in the same `scenarioName` as the first? Does the second mapping's `requiredScenarioState` match the `newScenarioState` in the first mapping? I don't think I quite understand the mappings/order that is causing problems